Updated Homepage Widgets feedback
The recent design update introduced widgets on the homepage, these have just been updated. Some feedback below.



Reputation

"Congrats! You’re ranked #324 this year."
Better, but still quite pointless (as pointed out by @Thom A) .
Would be nice if the reputation was clickable to go to your reputation tag (there is a button that does that but removed after going to the reputation screen)



Badge progress

No need for the gear icon.
There is already a 'Choose which badge to track' option on my profile. I don't need that on my homescreen. Not something we'll do daily.



Watched tags

Both buttons have exactly the same purposes, don't see the value of having 2 of them
The 'remove' button on mobile is too small for your fingers, already removed a few by accident.



Since there are 2 buttons, why not

'See all' just shows all tags in modal without delete option
'Gear icon' enabled 'edit'; shows all tags *with the option to delete'


There is also a bug with the 2 tabs, changing from 'watched' to 'ignored' does not move the 'active' styling on mobile:






Honestly, the  "Congrats! You’re ranked # this year." is pointless in my opinion, ~99.99998% of the community will never see it, as it'll only be displayed to users in the top 400 for the year.

Completely agree that is still useless, but yea, it's better then showing me how to earn reputation I guess. They need to fill the whitespaces somehow ;)

I'd suggest showing your daily review quota bar instead, but I don't think this applies to most users...

it's better then showing me how to earn reputation For those of us under 25k it shows what's the next privilege at how many rep.

An image for those with too much rep (oh how the tables have turned now!)- the reputation widget listing the next privilege instead

That's way more "exciting" than my widget, @ipodtouch0218 .

Boah, I don't notice much difference with the previous/first iteration: "Next privilege" now in the 'Reputation' box instead of "Asking/Answering/Editing", OK why not... // And the 'Overflow Blog' Posts have shifted by a few pixels to the left to "justify" not including their Icon... => Still fairly useless Design/Functionality...

Disagree with removing the gear icon; unless you know where else this information is presented, it's unobvious how to make changes if you remove the gear. The best fix would be to remove this ridiculous banner anyway.

They seem to be rolling this stuff out iteratively; it has already been admitted as much that the questions you get on your homepage are in no way picked any smarter than before yet and thus are likely actually not of interest to you still, regardless of the claims the page makes about it. So I'm pretty sure the see all link going to the edit tags page is a temporary hackfix too.

@Gimby is correct about our process here. We've aimed to release early and often, get feedback and iterate. The feedback here on meta is a big part of that, so thank you!

Regarding the rep widget text, there are currently 4 versions. Under 25 rep sees "Earn rep by...", users without all privileges see "Next privilege at...", top ranked users see "Congrats! You’re ranked...", everyone else (including me!) sees the empty one. Open to suggestions there

@Connell The feedback I've seen so far is mainly that people don't want these widgets (or the welcome message) at all, and there should least be the option to remove them. It would be nice to see an iteration based on that feedback.

The "new" watched tags widget is now MUCH less useful than it was before. This is (or rather was as of right now) the main interface I found interesting questions to answer:

Go to the homepage at https://stackoverflow.com
Find the "Watched Tags" widget in the right side, click on the tag I'm interested in.
Answer questions for the tag.

Now, the widget has moved in the homepage (but not on any other page) which is inconsistent and always required my to think a bit more where I find this.
Even worse, the homepage widget does not show all of my watched tags anymore, removing my ability to quickly filter interesting questions. The new widget only shows a few tags and hides the rest behind a "See all" link.
However, even after the additional click on this link, I can't navigate to the tag anymore, as "See all" apparently means "Edit my watched tags".
This change thus severely hinders my ability to quickly find interesting questions to answer while the original interface was quite efficient.
Thus, I'm in favor of just rolling back this change entirely.

There both still useless. 1 click more to see all tags isn't that bad compared to 3 scroll drags on mobile. But for desktop I completely agree.
